# Puma main process on exit callback

Tags: ruby, puma

How to execute ruby code just before Puma main process shuts down?
Now I am gracefully shutting down Puma from the action with this:

```
Process.kill("INT", Process.ppid)
```

and when all workers are down I need to execute ruby code.

```
at_exit do
  puts 'bye...'
end
```

Will be executed after each process exit and I need callback after all workers are exited.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean.  Do you need something that executes after each worker exits, or right before Puma stops?  You already mention `at_exit` so can you explain why that doesn't work for you?

Comment: It's fairly hacky, but you can use `on_worker_boot` to know if you are in a worker process or not. And since the main process will exit last, all workers would have exited at that point. So you should just check in the `at_exit` block if you are in the main process or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small hacky way to do it...

Add a global constant to your `config.ru` (or setup) file:

```
ROOT_PROCESS_ID = Process.pid
```

Than you can do something like:

```
at_exit do
  if(Process.pid == ROOT_PROCESS_ID)
    puts 'bye...'
  end
end
```

This isn't Puma specific, so it should work even when you change servers (if you ever switch).